# asp.net website button

Tags: asp.net

I need some help for my website.

I have three buttons, I need some help to link them to a content area that I have on the site.
When I press button `one` the content will change like `<h1>Button one<h1>` and the the rest of the code will follow . I have already the content setup so only I need is a example for the button code. The rest of the website will be the same.I am using asp.net c# 4.0

Comment: are you knowing what you do ? Please provide more code / explanation

Comment: Add your code with question. So we can see what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to change the content of Content Area on click of button. For that you need to handle the click event of button and change the content on click function. Read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To make h1 accessible from code-behind:

```
<h1 runat="server" id="H1Control">Button one<h1>
```

Then on YourBtn_Click() method assign new value this way:

```
H1Control.InnerHtml = "New text";
```

Comment: Okey I will make a new post, sorry I am new to ask quesiten her sorry about that

Comment: it is not necessarily to say 'thanks' everytime. just mark as right answer or vote if it's helps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As your suggests,I think u want to change the content within `<h1></h1>`.Here is the code to do that.

```
<h1 runat="server" id="something">Button 1</h1>
```

In code behind inside button click event do this..

```
something.InnerHTML="new text"
```